# stdarg.h reads too many arguments

Tags: c++

```
void wczytaj(N nazwa, O x1, ...) {
    va_list arg;
    O x;
    ...
    va_start (arg, x1);
    for (x = x1; x; x = va_arg(arg, O)) {
        w.punkt.push_back(x);
        cout << "DODANO " << x << endl;
    }
    va_end (arg);
    ...
```

I'm using it like this

```
s.wczytaj(n, x1, x2, x3);
```

where n is "asd", x1 = 1, x2 = 2, x3 = 3;

On output I can see

```
DODANO 1
DODANO 2
DODANO 3
DODANO 1081714496
```

Comment: Don't use `va_list`, especially in member functions. And you need to know the number of the arguments, `va_arg` will happily read the entire memory if it can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variadic function arguments are **not** typesafe, or any kind of 'safe' for that matter. It is *your* responsibility to communicate to your function how many arguments there are and what their types are.

In your code, the only thing that makes the loop terminate is when `x` evaluates as false. Your data, obscurely typed as it is, seems to consist of integral values, and that would necessitate your last variadic argument to be zero, which it isn't in your example.

Try calling the function wtih `(n, x1, x2, x3, 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <iostream>
void zytaj(int n, ...) {
  int i;
  va_list arg;
  va_start (arg, n); 
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int val = va_arg(arg, int);
    std::cout << val << std::endl;
  }
  va_end (arg);
}

int main()
{
  zytaj(3, 4, 1, 7); 
  return 0;
}
```